# Banner slider not showing

Tags: extensions, magento-1.6

I've added the [banner-slider](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider.html) extension to my Magento.
But I seem to have a problem where the slider is not showing up :(

I've added the following block to my cms home-page:

```
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="1"}}
```

I've added the slider (id=1) with manage sliders and added some banners to it.
I've positioned the slider to a custom position with the correct width and height.
The slider is enabled and has a mode set to it. (only show title is disabled)

But it doesn't show the slider in the front-end...
What am I doing wrong?

I've contacted the developer, but I didn't get an answer :(

Thanks for the help

Comment: Found the solution myself:
You need to set the start date for the banners 1 day earlier than the day you created the slider.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution myself: You need to set the start date for the banners 1 day earlier than the day you created the slider.

Comment: if you set slider date before 1 date than your slider works.........thanks!