# Magento 1.9 Banner Slider is not displayed on the frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, banner-slider

I set my slider and my banners. I inserted the block in the cms page with the correct ID but the slider is not displayed.
I checked this post too: [Banner slider not showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10871/73766)
If I try to change the banner date it is saved on 01/01/1970 at 01:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Locate **app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/controllers/Adminhtml/BannersliderController.php** file

Add this function

```
protected function _getDate($string)
{
    $date = explode('/', $string);
    $parts = explode(' ', $date[2]);
    $year = $parts[0];
    $time = $parts[1];
    return $year . '-' . $date[1] . '-' . $date[0] . ' ' . $time . ':00';
}
```

And use in `saveAction()`, this way

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        ...
        try {
             $data['start_time']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp($this->_getDate($data['start_time'])));
             $data['end_time']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp($this->_getDate($data['end_time'])));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        $model = Mage::getModel('bannerslider/bannerslider');
        $model->setData($data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        ...
```

This fixed the issue for us, although maybe you'd need some additional changes. That depends by which module version you are using

Comment: I modified it this way but it does not work. There is something wrong? [link](https://www.4shared.com/s/fb2sNFtPwgm)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
The problem is the date format of banners:
the datetimepicker produces a date in local format (in my case `DD/MM/YYYY`) but the plugin reads the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.
I simply entered the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format by hand without using the datetimepicker

Comment: Well, that's exactly the purpose of _getDate function in my answer :)